# Easist way to moderate an image via a php GET callback request?

Tags: 7, media, rules

I want to add some code that allows me to use an image moderation service called Webpurify http://www.webpurify.com/image-moderation/documentation/callback/. I can send the url request using a rule (or using a hook via a custom module) and they send a callback GET request to a URL I specify, with the imageid and the moderation status directly in the url like this - http://www.yoururl.com/imgcallback.php?imgid=43534dfdfg3453sffsd&status=1. What's the best way to setup a call back page or url in Drupal? It's very simple it just publishes the node if accepted and deletes it if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a custom module, you would create a menu item and callback:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {

   $items=array();

   $items['imgcallback'] = array(
     'title' => 'Webpurify Response',
     'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_imgcallback',
     'access callback' => TRUE,
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );

   // create any other custom menu items here

   return $items;

}

function YOURMODULE_imgcallback() {

   $imgid=$_GET['imgid'];    // this is the ?imgid=....
   $status=$_GET['status'];  // this is the &status=...

   if ($status) {
     // this is where you would publish the node, but for now...
     return 'Webpurify liked image ' . $imgid;
   }
   else {
     // this is where you would delete the node, but for now...
     return 'Webpurify didn\'t like image ' . $imgid;
   }

}
```

Clear your caches and now you will have a url on your host:

```
www.YOURHOST.com/imgcallback?imgid=foobarbaz&status=1
```

that will return `Webpurify liked image foobarbaz` and

```
www.YOURHOST.com/imgcallback?imgid=baddabing&status=0
```

that will return `Webpurify didn't like your image baddabing`

It's up to you to change all of that to the publish/delete logic/functionality as I don't know how you are mapping imgid to node, etc.  Just realize if your users can somehow figure that out, they can/could/would/might call this url directly with whatever status they desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a path with [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and let the call back point to this path. The call back method of the menu entry handles the call from the service, does any processing needed and finaly does a [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) to your node.

Have a look at the [commerce adyen module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_adyen). It provides two entries in hook_menu which handle call backs from the adyen payment gateway.