# Only display image field when administrator approves it

Tags: media, workflows

I'm building an advertising website using Drupal 7, in my case anyone can add an advertisement without any restriction, except that the images should be hidden first until the website admin approves it.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36154/easist-way-to-moderate-an-image-via-a-php-get-callback-request

Comment: To create such a publishing workflow, I think you need the Workbench module (https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) and more in particular the Workbench Media module (https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_media)

Comment: I should think this can easily be done with a hidden 'approved' field and the Rules module, or even Themekey if you want to get fancy about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution for my case.

I solved the problem in the following way:

1. Install Entity API, Entity Reference, Automatic Entity Label and Automatic Nodetitles modules.
2. Create new content type named 'image' and apply Automatic Entity Label to it.
3. Create new content type named 'classified' and create an Entity Reference field that can be used to point to an 'image' node.
4. Now if you create a 'classified' node and an 'image' node from 'classified' node itself, the information appears without an image because the image content will be unpublished by default (until the admin publishes it).

Finally, thanks a lot for your support and help especially J. Reynolds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [File admin](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_admin) .

> File admin extends the File entity module to add administrative
>   options to files, including published, promoted, and sticky status.

It has a dependency on [File entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity), which is a prerequisite when working with files as first class citizens.

Please also look at File admin's issue queue. A lot of extra functionality can be added via a few select patches.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help
i tried but the issue is that i can't change the properties for any entity field always coming error message [access forbidden ] when saving the entity
please check this link to my issue
https://www.drupal.org/node/2396851

Comment: @JavaTrainner Sorry to hear it did not work for you. If it was you who added the bug report in the issue queue, please give more context. At the moment the maintainers will not be able to reproduce the error. At the very least create a fresh install of Drupal with just the module and dependencies in question. Test the module and start adding the other modules you have installed one by one until it fails, then add that info to your issue. The module developers give their free time to develop contrib modules and it is the least we can do.

Comment: thanks a lot for help
I already find the solution
the bug is you can't use image/* in mimetypes you should add one by one like image/png, image/....etc
but i get now is when you add article with picture it's appear while in file tab the image added to articles is unpublished

Comment: Remember to check and set permissions for file_entity and file_admin. Also check issue queue for added functionality and help.

Comment: i already check it but nothing wrong, the unpublished image file is not appear if you try to access it but if you open the article that have the same image file it will appear.
so really i'm confusing how i will fix that